# Override Problem for Custom Design on Product - Magento

Tags: templates, magento, magento-1.4

I am running several sites in several different languages off of single instance of Magento.

There are two main styles:

- Site 1
- Site 2

Each site has some customizations based on language, so each shop view has an some templates defined:

- Site 2 - DE
- Site 2 - UK

Now the problem is that when I apply a product level design, it forgets about the language level definition and skips back to the main definition.

I want it to work like this:

- Site 2

  - Site 2 DE

    - Product Style

Instead it seems to work like this :

- Site 2

  - <strike>Site 2 DE</strike>
  - Product Style

Where Site 2 DE is not ignored because a custom product style has been defined.  How can I get the first hierarchy to work so that my product styles do not override the language styles completely?

#### Images

Here are some images to help you understand my configuration

Site level configuration
[image]

Store level configuration
[image]

Product level configuration
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't been able to accomplish what i set out to do with the template overrides, but I have "solved" the problem another way.

Instead of trying to override the "Custom Design" I have overridden the specific template through the "Custom Layout Update" area.  So I moved the phtml files (renamed uniquely) the the master template and then did something like this in the "Custom Layout Option"

```
  <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped-beamclamp.phtml" />
  </reference>
```

Where the template name is the new name.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you applied design to the product you edit Global config. Try to switch to the Store View (Site 2 DE) and apply custom design for the product.

Comment: I tried that (I've attached some images to my post) but it's still overriding the store level design.